# how to synchronously setState of multiple values in react?

Tags: reactjs, synchronization

I have a React component with 4 different state values:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            intents: [],
            selected_tags: [],
            unselected_tags: []};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.checkIntersection = this.checkIntersection.bind(this);
        this.setTags = this.setTags.bind(this);
}
```

the `value` updates as the user types a message, a server response populates `intents`, and the other two follow a logic according to the items in `intents`:

```
this.setState({
    intent: ['a','b','c'...n],
    selected_tags: data.filter(tag => this.checkIntersection(['b','c','d'], this.state.intent).size !== 0), 
    unselected_tags: data.filter(tag => !this.state.selected_tags.includes(tag))
)}
```

The problem is that I can't seem to update the latter three synchronously (`intents`, `selected_tags` and `unselected_tags`). This is crucial since the content of `selected_tags` depend on `intents`, and the content of `unselected_tags` depends on `selected_tags`.

I did manage to force `selected_tags` to wait for `intents` to populate using Promises `.then()` and `unselected_tags` to wait for `selected_tags` using `setTimeout()`.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3001', {
    params: {
      text: this.state.value
    }
  })
.then(response => this.setState({
    intent: [....])
}))
.then(setTags)

setTags() {
    if (this.state.intent !== []) {
      this.setState( {
        selected_tags: data.filter(tag => this.checkIntersection(tag.intents, this.state.intent).size !== 0)
  });
  setTimeout(this.setState({ 
    unselected_tags: data.filter(tag => !this.state.selected_tags.includes(tag))}), 0)
   }
}
```

However, I'm pretty sure this is not the 'React' way of doing this, mainly because I don't know how long the server will take to respond in realtime, so using `setTimeout` could be a bad practice. On the other hand, I didn't manage to use `ComponentDidUpdate()` either, since `value` updates instantly as I type so it doesn't wait for `intents` to populate.

I suspect `getDerivedStateFromProps()` might be helpful in these kind of situations, but I didn't find any *real* use of this function online (with a context and all).
Is there an equivalent to `ComponentDidUpdate()` where I can choose what specific kind of update in the state to wait for?

Generally speaking, I am not sure  how to reconcile my flow with the react lifecycle the react way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First solution (not bound to React).**

Edited. See Kevin Raoofi answer below.

**Second solution (React).** Set state has callback that will be called sychronously after state will be set. Code can be something like this:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3001', {
  params: {
    text: this.state.value
  }
})
.then(response => this.setState({
  intent: [....],
}, () => this.setSelectedTags()))
setSelectedTags() {
  if (this.state.intent !== []) {
    this.setState({
      selected_tags: data.filter(tag => this.checkIntersection(tag.intents, this.state.intent).size !== 0)
    }, () => this.setUnselectedTags());
  }
}
setUnselectedTags() {
  this.setState({
    unselected_tags: data.filter(tag => !this.state.selected_tags.includes(tag))
  });
}
```

But this feels like spaghetti...

Comment: spaghetti spaghetti, but it actually worked! I made slight modifications, such that instead of defining new functions as callback, I called an embedded setState directly, like so:  
`  .then(response => this.setState({
    intent: [...],
  }, () => this.setState({
    selected_tags: ....
  }, () => this.setState({
    unselected_tags: ...
  })))) ` Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In general, don't put derived state in your React state. You should, instead, elect to generate derived state for each render. The point is to make sure your state is valid at all times. However, there's really not much of an issue in using derived state if you make sure it's never invalid.

The problem here is that you're updating the intent and then you're updating the derived state later when you should just do it at once.

Just do:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3001', {
    params: {
      text: this.state.value
    }
  })
.then(response => {
    const intent = [....]
    const selected_tags = data.filter(tag => this.checkIntersection(tag.intents, intent).size !== 0)
    cont unselected_tags = data.filter(tag => !selected_tags.includes(tag))

    this.setState({ intent, selected_tags, unselected_tags })
})
```